# tensorflow.js model.predict() Prints Tensor [[NaN],]

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow.js

I am completely new to Machine learning and also to tensorflow.js, I am trying to predict the values of the next set but it is giving me "NaN" in result. What am  I doing wrong ?

Following [this Github example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/blob/master/getting_started/index.js)

```
 async function myFirstTfjs(arr) {
    // Create a simple model.
    const model = tf.sequential();
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [2]}));

    // Prepare the model for training: Specify the loss and the optimizer.
    model.compile({
      loss: 'meanSquaredError',
      optimizer: 'sgd'
    });
    const xs = tf.tensor([[1,6],
        [2,0],
        [3,1],
        [4,2],
        [5,3],
        [6,4],
        [7,5],
        [8,6],
        [9,0],
        [10,1],
        [11,2],
        [12,3],
        [13,4],
        [14,5],
        [15,6],
        [16,0],
        [17,1],
        [18,2],
        [19,3],
        [20,4],
        [21,5],
        [22,6],
        [23,0],
        [24,1],
        [25,2],
        [26,3]]);
    const ys = tf.tensor([104780,30280,21605,42415,32710,30385,35230,97795,31985,34570,35180,30095,36175,57300,104140,30735,28715,36035,34515,42355,38355,110080,26745,35315,40365,30655], [26, 1]);
    // Train the model using the data.
    await model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 500});
    // Use the model to do inference on a data point the model hasn't seen.
  model.predict(tf.tensor(arr, [1, 2])).print();
  }
  myFirstTfjs([28,5]);
```

Answer (score 4):

What's happening is that the large values in `ys` are leading to a very large error.  That large error, in combination with the (default) learning rate, are causing the model to overcorrect and be unstable.  The model will converge if you lower the learning rate.

```
const learningRate = 0.0001;
const optimizer = tf.train.sgd(learningRate);

model.compile({
  loss: 'meanSquaredError',
  optimizer: optimizer,      
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much it work ,atleast got some output. But it iss  not giving quite correct value see the chart on sunday sales are very high https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dxv8BWIEJbZ0woEp_saPYM-49Tp8rs0PtOz3Mp9HFvY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you figure this out at all?

Comment: not yet I am trying to find how can i train model better

Answer (score 3):

Try convert your output to more readable and change your optimizer

```
var pred = model.predict(tf.tensor(arr, [1, 2]));
    var readable_output = pred.dataSync();
    console.log(readable_output);
```